# Need Show configurable product Swatches in Home page

Tags: magento-2.1, product, cms-block, home-page, configurable-swatches

I need to show the **Configurable Product Swatches** in **Home page** by **CMS block**.

Tried using -:

https://github.com/zaibi099/Magento/tree/master/Pakgentors/Swatches

Its working fine with XML layout, but not showing swatches when I try to call it from CMS block.

Answer (score 0):

### Showing Configurable Swatches in Home Page

Here, You can try the following method, For me it's working

1. In Admin->content->pages
2. select Home Page and edit
3. Click the design Tab from left side

In **Layout Update XML** Column add following Code

```
<referenceContainer name="content"> 
    <container name="home-page-full-block2" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-page-full-block2">    
                <block name="topselling.swatchrenderer">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
    </block>
                 <block class="Ashik\ModuleName\Block\Topselling" name="productlist3" template="ModuleCompany_ModuleName::topselling.phtml">
              <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="topselling.swatchrenderer" as="topselling.toprenderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
              </block>
          </block>
   </container>

</referenceContainer>
```

finally go to your block **Ashik\ModuleName\Block\Topselling.php** add following code

```
public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());

        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function getDetailsRenderer($type = null)
    {
        if ($type === null) {
            $type = 'default';
        }

        $rendererList = $this->getDetailsRendererList();
        if ($rendererList) {
            return $rendererList->getRenderer($type, 'default');
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function getDetailsRendererList()
    {
        return $this->getDetailsRendererListName() ? $this->getLayout()->getBlock(
            $this->getDetailsRendererListName()
        ) : $this->getChildBlock(
            'topselling.toprenderers'
        );
    }
```

In view page get swatches from **echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product);**

---

Comment: Thanks For the reply... This is not the solution i am looking for..it work same as that XML i have tried..
i need to get it from Static CMS block .. https://prnt.sc/il8xxv

Comment: **In CMS HomePage-> Layout Update->add this code only, it will work **`<referenceContainer name="content"> 
    <container name="home-page" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-page">    
                <block name="homepage.toprenderers">
        <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
    </block> </container>

</referenceContainer>`

Comment: No.. Its not Working..

Answer (score 0):

**In CMS HomePage-> Layout Update->add this code only, Hopefully it will work **

```
<referenceBlock name="homepage.swatchrenderer">
          <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
          <container name="topproduct" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="topproduct">
                  <block class="Pakgentors\Swatches\Block\Productslist" name="productlist" template="Pakgentors_Swatches::products.phtml">
                      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="homepage.swatchrenderer" as="homepage.toprenderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                      </block>
                  </block>
           </container>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: i tried this before posting.. its working.. But its on **CMS page** and it's calling the .phtml file in XML itself..its not possible for my condition.. I need to get this via **Admin> Content > CMS > Static block**.. already share the screen -> prnt.sc/il8xxv

Comment: @SUBINCHANDRAN you need to create a **block** else it won't come, In that block you can give condition, what product should come in product collections